# flutter (follow unfollow) buttom It works strangely

Tags: flutter, dart

When I press “follow” it works, but when I press “unfollow” one click does not work, but when I press again it works. I will attach a video of the application and the problem.

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/jP4Pp1mqrjc

this is my full code

```html
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_rating_bar/flutter_rating_bar.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:hallo_doctor_client/app/utils/constants/style_constants.dart';
import 'package:hallo_doctor_client/app/service/doctor_service.dart';
import 'package:hallo_doctor_client/app/service/user_service.dart';

var userId = userService.getUserId();

class DoctorCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String doctorPhotoUrl;
  final String doctorName;
  final String doctorHospital;
  final String doctorPrice;
  final String doctorCategory;
  final int totalrating;
  final int ratingnumbers;

  final VoidCallback onTap;
  const DoctorCard(
      {Key? key,
      required this.doctorPhotoUrl,
      required this.doctorName,
      required this.doctorHospital,
      required this.doctorPrice,
      required this.doctorCategory,
      required this.totalrating,
      required this.ratingnumbers,
      required this.onTap})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DoctorCard> createState() => _DoctorCardState();
}

class _DoctorCardState extends State<DoctorCard> {
  bool isFollowing = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    checkaddornot();
  }

  Future<dynamic> checkaddornot() async {
    try {
      QuerySnapshot check = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Doctors')
          .where('doctorName', isEqualTo: widget.doctorName)
          .where('doctorHospital', isEqualTo: widget.doctorHospital)
          .where('favorite', arrayContains: userId)
          .get();

      if (check.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        return isFollowing = true;
      }
      //  if (check.docs.isEmpty) {
      //   return isFollowing = false;
      //   }
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: NetworkImage(widget.doctorPhotoUrl)),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Price'.tr,
                      style: priceTextStyle,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      widget.doctorPrice,
                      style: priceNumberTextStyle,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 160,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                              child: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
                                future: checkaddornot(),
                                builder: (BuildContext context, checkaddornot) {
                                  return ElevatedButton(
                                    child: Text(
                                        isFollowing ? 'unfollow' : 'follow'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isFollowing = !isFollowing;
                                      });
// هنا يمكنك تنفيذ الأوامر المرتبطة بـ follow أو unfollow

                                      //  UserService().addtofavoritelist(UserService().getUserId(),doctorName,doctorHospital,doctorPhotoUrl);

                                      if (isFollowing) {
// أمر عند الضغط للمتابعة
                                        Text('Following...');

                                        UserService().addtofavoritelist(
                                            UserService().getUserId(),
                                            widget.doctorName,
                                            widget.doctorHospital,
                                            widget.doctorPhotoUrl);
                                      } else {
// أمر عند الضغط لإلغاء المتابعة
                                        Text('Unfollowing...');
                                        UserService().removefromfavoritelist(
                                            UserService().getUserId(),
                                            widget.doctorName,
                                            widget.doctorHospital,
                                            widget.doctorPhotoUrl);
                                      }
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 7,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            widget.doctorName,
                            style: doctorNameStyle,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 7,
                          ),
                          TextWithIcon(
                            text: widget.doctorCategory,
                            imageAsset: 'assets/icons/Stethoscope.png',
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 5),
                          TextWithIcon(
                            text: widget.doctorHospital,
                            imageAsset: 'assets/icons/hospital_icon.png',
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 7,
                          ),
                          RatingBarIndicator(
                              rating: widget.totalrating == null ||
                                      widget.ratingnumbers == null
                                  ? 4.5
                                  : widget.totalrating / widget.ratingnumbers,
                              itemCount: 5,
                              itemSize: 20,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Icon(
                                    Icons.star,
                                    color: Colors.amber,
                                  )),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: widget.onTap,
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 40,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                            color: Colors.blue),
                        child: Text(
                          'Book Consultation'.tr,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 77, 75, 114)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextWithIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextWithIcon({Key? key, required this.text, required this.imageAsset})
      : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final String imageAsset;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: [
          WidgetSpan(
            child: Image.asset(
              imageAsset,
              height: 20,
              width: 20,
            ),
          ),
          WidgetSpan(
              child: SizedBox(
            width: 6,
          )),
          TextSpan(
              text: text,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code is responsible for giving a value to the isfollowing variable from the Firebase database

```html
bool isFollowing = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    checkaddornot();
  }

  Future<dynamic> checkaddornot() async {
    try {
      QuerySnapshot check = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Doctors')
          .where('doctorName', isEqualTo: widget.doctorName)
          .where('doctorHospital', isEqualTo: widget.doctorHospital)
          .where('favorite', arrayContains: userId)
          .get();

      if (check.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        return isFollowing = true;
      }
      //  if (check.docs.isEmpty) {
      //   return isFollowing = false;
      //   }
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

This code is responsible for executing orders in the event of follow or unnollow

```html
FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
                                future: checkaddornot(),
                                builder: (BuildContext context, checkaddornot) {
                                  return ElevatedButton(
                                    child: Text(
                                        isFollowing ? 'unfollow' : 'follow'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isFollowing = !isFollowing;
                                      });
// هنا يمكنك تنفيذ الأوامر المرتبطة بـ follow أو unfollow

                                      //  UserService().addtofavoritelist(UserService().getUserId(),doctorName,doctorHospital,doctorPhotoUrl);

                                      if (isFollowing) {
// أمر عند الضغط للمتابعة
                                        Text('Following...');

                                        UserService().addtofavoritelist(
                                            UserService().getUserId(),
                                            widget.doctorName,
                                            widget.doctorHospital,
                                            widget.doctorPhotoUrl);
                                      } else {
// أمر عند الضغط لإلغاء المتابعة
                                        Text('Unfollowing...');
                                        UserService().removefromfavoritelist(
                                            UserService().getUserId(),
                                            widget.doctorName,
                                            widget.doctorHospital,
                                            widget.doctorPhotoUrl);
                                      }
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
```